# Why can't Java Lambda throw an checked exception

Tags: java, exception, lambda, checked-exceptions, unchecked-exception

I'm learning Java and am a bit confused, why Lambda Expressions can't throw checked exceptions. Anyone has an understandable explanation for this?

I read through this post:
[Java 8 Lambda function that throws exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception/59824314#59824314)
and this one:
[java throwing checked exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163032/java-throwing-checked-exceptions)
but both werent helping me. I also read multiple articles on google, but they all say that its not possible, but not why.

Comment: The first question you link to shows that *a lambda can in fact throw a checked exception*. Did you read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much a method. If the method signature is declared to throw a checked exception, then a checked exception can be thrown inside of the lambda.

Imagine if you could.

```
Runnable r = ()->{ throw new CheckedException();};
```

Now our imaginary runnable.run can be called, but the caller will not know it has to handle a checked exception.

Callable on the other hand does throw an Exception.

```
Callable c = ()->{ throw new CheckedException();};
```

This works fine, because Callable.call is declared to throw an exception. You don't know the specific type of exception, but you have to handle one.